# Media query properties being overwriiten by other breakpoints

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I need to apply a few styles depending on the width of the viewport. To do this I wrote a few media queries but on running them I found that the smaller media queries are being overwritten.

Code sample: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/joLVGZ

**HTML**

```
<div>
  hello
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
  height: 200px;
}
/*
 * Less than 576px
*/
@media screen and (max-width: 576px) {
  div {
    background-color: red;
  }
}

/*
 * Less than 768px
 */
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  div {
    background-color: green;
  }
}

/*
 * Less than 992px 
*/
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  div {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}

/*
 * Less than 1200px
*/
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  div {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
}

/*
Greator than 1200px
*/
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  div {
    background-color: grey;
  }
}
```

In the sample I tried changing the browser size but the background color set at 992px (Yellow) overwrites the other breakpoints and the color remains yellow for all other smaller size.

How do I make sure styles do not overwrite other styles? Are my media queries written wrongly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reverse the order of your media queries. The way you have them, the second-to-last one overwrites all previous ones, since `max-width: 1200px` applies to everything below 1200px.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the order of `@media`:

```css
div {
  height: 200px
}
/* More than 1200px */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  div {
    background-color: grey;
  }
}

/* Less than 1200px */
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  div {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
}
/* Less than 992px */
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) { 
  div {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
/* Less than 768px */
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  div {
    background-color: green;
  }
}
/* Less than 576px */
@media screen and (max-width: 576px) {
  div {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```